# How to calculate the difference in the average check for M/F users for a certain period in PostgresSQL?

Tags: sql

There are two tables:

Trips (order_id, user_id, order_dt, order_cost) - all taxi trips

Users (user_id, gender) - table of users, where the gender of the user (M / W) is marked

Required: Calculate the difference in the average check for M/W users over a certain period (using any method in SQL, Python, Excel, etc.) Explain why it may differ

My solution to the problem: To calculate the revenue, you need to multiply the average check at the end of the month by the number of customers who made a purchase from you. To calculate the average check, you need to divide the revenue for the day (or the period of interest to us) by the number of checks, the resulting amount is the average check for the day. It can differ only from the number of male and female users.

1)in SQL
-- calculation of the average check

```
SELECT SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id)
FROM taxi AS t
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.gender
```

-- difference I think so

```
SELECT avg(order_cost) filter(where gender = 'M') - avg(order_cost) filter(where gender = 'W') 
FROM taxi AS t 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
```

But they tell me it's wrong. I don't understand where I have an error: in the syntax or should I use a subquery, window functions? I'm new to SQL, so I don't understand how to do it right here.

2. In Excel, this task is calculated in 2 minutes with pulling up the floor, the summary and the calculated field of the average check.
3. In Python, I would use the Pandas and Numpy libraries

Comment: What platform are you using?  Very few allow filter and I don't think any allow it without an OVER clause.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why can't FILTER be used in Postgres?

Comment: I believe postgres is the only db that uses it.  But you did not say you were using postgres so I have to believe you are using generic SQL which does not include filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
SELECT SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id)
FROM taxi AS t
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.gender
```

Will give two rows -- one for male and one for female.

This will give for male only

```
SELECT SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id)
FROM taxi AS t
INNER JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.gender = 'M'
```

Here is how I would do it, the simple way

```
SELECT SUM(AM.AVG_O) / COUNT(AM.USER_ID) AS M_AVG,
       SUM(AW.AVG_O) / COUNT(AW.USER_ID) AS W_AVG,
       SUM(AM.AVG_O) / COUNT(AM.USER_ID) - SUM(AW.AVG_O) / COUNT(AW.USER_ID) AS DIFF
FROM taxi AS t
JOIN (
  SELECT USER_ID, SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id) AS AVG_O
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.gender = 'M'
  GROUP BY USER_ID
) AS AM ON AM.USER_ID = T.USER_ID
JOIN (
  SELECT USER_ID, SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id) AS AVG_O
  FROM users u
  WHERE u.gender = 'W'
  GROUP BY USER_ID
) AS AW ON AW.USER_ID = T.USER_ID
```

You could be fancy and reduce this to only one sub-query but this is clearer to understand.  (Use CASE in main select)

---

Looking at it again I realized it is possible to simplify since you don't care about each user in the outer query.  A cross join feels bad, but there is only 1 row in each of these tables so the result is just one row:

```
SELECT AM.AVG_O AS M_AVG,
       AW.AVG_O AS W_AVG,
       AM.AVG_O - AW.AVG AS DIFF
FROM taxi AS t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id) AS AVG_O
  FROM users 
  WHERE u.gender = 'M'
) 
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT SUM(u.order_cost) / COUNT(u.order_id) AS AVG_O
  FROM users 
  WHERE u.gender = 'W'
)
```

Comment: The CROSS JOIN option looks brilliant. But it's not clear how it works. I'll go read the PostgreSQL documentation...

Comment: The first option with the usual join is not working in my opinion. there, by user_id, M and F are actually joined. And one user_id cannot be M and F at the same time

Comment: can replace with GROUP BY u.gender?

Comment: did you try the first option --- were you getting results you did not expect?  The code looks very correct to me -- I've used code like this in countless queries.

Comment: I can replace group by because we are only looking a single gender and we want to get the average there is no need to group by the users.  average works that way

Comment: You're welcome @Григорий -- good luck